# org/eclipse/swt/custom/TableTree error when using a BPEL process?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ode, bpel

I added ODE Server in my eclipse environment and is succesfully started.

Now I have a problem with the BPEL process file, after creating it in a BPEL project, whenever i try to get to the properties of an action i get the following error:

An error has occurred. See error log for more details. org/eclipse/swt/custom/TableTree

I'm using Eclipse JEE 2019-12, JDK 13, Tomcat 9.0.30, and ODE 1.3.8

[image: Error's screenshot]

Comment: TableTree was removed from SWT in Eclipse 4.12 (2019-12 is 4.14) see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475833)

Comment: Thank's, i installed eclipse 4.11 and it worked perfectly

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) post your answer and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Comment: I am using eclipse 2020-06 (4.16.0), I am facing the same issue. How to get rid of this issue.